# sscanf + c99 not working on some platforms?

Tags: c, gcc, debian, centos, scanf

When I compile a simple Hello World! program that uses the sscanf function on my local Debian lenny x64, it works. But when I upload the same program to the server running CentOS x86, it will not work. If I do not use sscanf, then the program works on both computers.

gcc -std=c99 -O2 -pipe -m32

If I compile it with sscanf but without -std=c99, then it works on both computers.

gcc -O2 -pipe -m32

What is the problem with sscanf and c99 on CentOS x86 ? I thought that compiling with the -m32 flag would work on all Linuxes ? (I have limited access to the CentOS server, so I do not have access to error messages.)

Comment: You should probably show a few lines around the code using the `sscanf()` function and a little bit of a description of what exactly you mean by "it will not work".

Comment: "Works" vs. "not working" is not a meaningful description of a problem.

Answer (score 6):

Probably the CentOS box is using an old version of glibc. Since the nonstandard GNU extensions to their scanf implementation ended up making glibc conflict with c99, they added a nasty hack of redirecting `*scanf` to `__isoc99_*scanf` when `-std=c99` is in use; if your copy of glibc is missing the `__isoc99_sscanf` symbol, the program will then fail to run.

Static linking, or linking to a different libc without ugly backwardsness-compatibility hacks, would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you uploading the binary or the source and then recompiling? If you are uploading the binary, you are probably running into a library compatibility issue between Debian and CentOS.

If that is the case, upload the source only and recompile on CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have permission to compile @ CentOS, then try compiling a static binary. You can use dietlibc which makes smaller binaries than glibc or try EGLIBC which is the default C library that Debian will use starting Debian "squeeze".

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the similar problem, it works @ Ubuntu 64-bit, but the compile fails @ CenseOS 64-bit (REHL5 desktop):

the error message is:

```
undefined reference to `__isoc99_sscanf@GLIBC_2.7'
```

when i copied the executable file compiled @Ubuntu to REHL5, and run it another error appeared:

```
elf file os abi invalid
```

it is compiled without flag -std=c99, i'm a newbie at C, and looking forword some workarounds, ex. add some flag.

Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CCFLAGS= -Wall -O2 -DLINUX -I../include

demos:linuxdemo.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o demoA linuxdemo.c -L../lib -lsense4 -lusb

    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o demoSO linuxdemo.c -lusb -lsense4

clean:
    rm -f demoA
    rm -f demoSO
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to update your glibc to 2.7

download the rpm package from here:
http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/8/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/

needs:

libc-common-2.7-2.x86_64.rpm

glibc-headers-2.7-2.x86_64.rpm

glibc-devel-2.7-2.x86_64.rpm

glibc-2.7-2.x86_64.rpm

command:

rpm -Uvh --aid --nodeps glibc-common-2.7-2.x86_64.rpm

rpm -Uvh --aid --nodeps glibc-headers-2.7-2.x86_64.rpm

rpm -Uvh --aid --nodeps glibc-devel-2.7-2.x86_64.rpm

rpm -Uvh --aid --nodeps glibc-2.7-2.x86_64.rpm